# Is there a file management library for the iPhone Documents folder?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am look for file management features, such as:

- folder listing
- file listing
- create/rename/delete folder
- rename/delete files
- move files among folders

via a UITableView. BSD-like licensed code preferred.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I'm not aware of any open-source ready to go components but what you want should be fairly easy to accomplish for somebody with a basic grasp of iPhone development. Check out the `NSFileManager` class for further direction.

Comment: Yes, I don't see how you could make file handling much simpler than dealing with NSFileManager.  For more on this, see the Low-Level File Management Programming Topics guide: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/Introduction.html